# mailto link on image not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, background-image, mailto

When a user clicks on the "send email" button, their default email application opens with the subject line: Request Information".

Can anyone tell me why this "mailto:" code will not work in IE7/8?  It works correctly in FF, Chrome and Safari.  I don't want to have to wrap up my image in an anchor tag, unless there's no other way.

HTML

```
<a href="mailto:info@mydomain.com?subject=Request Information" class="info-main">Send email</a>
```

CSS

```
.info-main {
background-image:url('/i/info_email_button.png') no-repeat;
display:block;
    height:123px;
    width:24px;
text-indent:-9999px;
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Url-Encode for spaces and special characters, that means:

```
<a href="mailto:info@mydomain.com?subject=Request%20Information" class="info-main">Send email</a>
```

Comment: I tried using the Url-Encode (above) but it's not working.  Clicking the image freezes IE and then it crashes.  I have to go to task manager to end the task because it takes so long to close IE

Comment: I hate IE.  I can't believe I have to add img markup in my html just to pacify that whack browser, man

Comment: Says the person who thinks it's acceptable/reasonable to indent text by negative a bazillion pixels...

Answer (score 3):

You should URL-encode your subject line. In this case, replace the space with either `+` or `%20`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both.  It does not launch the app.  As a matter of fact, when I click on the image, it totally freezes IE and in the status bar it displays the entire "mailto" code string.  I removed the subject property as well, but still it still doesn't work.  The cursor changes to the hand pointer, but nothing happens.

Comment: Need to get a new copy of IE for my laptop.  It works on other machines.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem with mailto: email links not working in IE9 and FirefoxF22 on PC and fixed it when changing the  element to regular ole div. So instead of:

```
    <button class="foo-btn"><a href="mailto:foo@bar.com">E-mail</a></button>
```

Try this for IE9:

```
    <div class="foo-btn"><a href="mailto:foo@bar.com">E-mail</a></div>
```

The other solutions I saw about adding  ...target="_blank" or it being a Google Analytics script conflict didn't solve the issue for me.